# Seeking design advice for a client-side look-up of a reference table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In a web-application, based on VB.net, I am struggling with how to implement a look-up function in a reference table. Specifically, I want users to be able to select a school from a reference table in several places in the application. The solution must work on client-side without a post-back, and the user can enter a name or address fragment to limit their available choice.

My first attempt involved a hidden div, expanded on client side, with a GridView that displayed the full set of schools, and a Javascript function that navigated and hid rendered  elements according to user entry of name or address. It worked, albeit became a serious performance hit when used with the entire 4,000 reference records due to slow rendering of table rows from the GridView.

At present, I am looking at an ObjectDataSource (cached), that I would use to manually render table entries in my div according to user selection. It seems very laborious and tricky from client side.

Is there an alternative, perhaps an aspx page that can open as dialog on top of the original one (without suffering a post-back?

At this time I am looking for design advice, hence no code to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identified three problems that you need to solve: you have a large amount of data that you need to query locally, you need some sort of a user interface to show the data, and you need to have some client-side data filtering logic.

If I were in your situation I would consider using a free 3rd party UI component from one of the many JavaScript libraries out there. There is no need to reinvent the wheel. UI components come with everything you need built-in: they can bind to local data efficiently and they have methods for filtering. I would give you some examples on how to implement it with Kendo UI, which is my weapon of choice, but similar solutions are available through a number of other frameworks.

**Data**

Firstly, I would recommend that you serialize the data from your reference table to JSON by using Json.NET or something similar. Then you would render the resulting string into a JavaScript variable on the page:

```
 var data = [{"SchoolName": "School One", "Address": "Address One"},
        {"SchoolName": "School Two", "Address": "Address Two"},...];
```

**UI**

It sounds like a grid would be overkill for this. I would use a drop-down list instead. Kendo UI offers a free one, which supports html templating that allows you to make its records look like a table. In other words you can have the school names in one column and the addresses in another. Here's an example of multi-column layout:

[image: Kendo dropdown]

Take a look here for more examples: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

**Filtering**

Finally, you would need to setup filtering on the drop-down component. By default it supports filtering based on one data field, however it can be easily setup to filter across all of your fields (school name, address, email, etc.). That is documented [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/dropdownlist-filter-multiple-properties).

As a conclusion I put together a quick example of how this component will work with local JSON data, multiple columns, and filtering: https://dojo.telerik.com/AvOLOrob

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really like the thought you put into this answer. I will attempt to hook up this solution and will mark the answer correct later (asap). Thank you.